# Qt, qss, increase/decrease font size by a factor

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

Is it possible to increase/decrease font size by a factor using qss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Qt Style Sheets Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) for the font-size property says:

> In this version of Qt, only pt and px metrics are supported.

So it still doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try scaling the value through code and then inserting back to stylesheet.

```
//nFontSize and nSomeFactor are your base font size and factor
widgetYouWantToSetFontSizeFor->setStyleSheet("font-size: "+QString::number(scaleUsingSomeFactor(nFontSize, nSomeFactor))+"pt;");
```

Although, I am not sure what you're looking for.